# Quering Postgresql digest function inside procedure works on pgadmin but not works by calling via Laravel

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4

recently I have created stored procedure in Postgres Sql which deals about with hashing passwords. When used via PgAdmin tool it works like a charm as stated below.

I have also installed extension pgcrypto.

```
SELECT horeca_user.update_token(
    1, //user_id
    1, //type
    'sdsfsdfs' //token
)
```

It works when called via pgadmin tool, but not inside laravel app as stated below.

```
$token=\DB::select("SELECT * from \"horeca_user\".update_token('$type', '$user_id', '$token')");
```

and finally this is my procedure code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION horeca_user.update_token(tp integer,userid integer,token character varying)
    RETURNS character varying
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
    PARALLEL UNSAFE
    COST 100
AS $BODY$ 
DECLARE uid INTEGER;
DECLARE tok character varying;
BEGIN
    uid:=0;
    Select count(*) as total from horeca_user.user_tokens where user_id=$2 into uid;

    if uid=0 THEN
       Insert into horeca_user.user_tokens(id, user_id, tip) values($3, $2, $1);
     else
       Update horeca_user.user_tokens set id=$3, tip=$1 where user_id=$2;
     END IF;

     SELECT encode(digest(token, 'sha256'), 'hex') as tt into tok;

     return tok;
END

$BODY$;
```

Comment: in PGAdmin you call SELECT horeca_user.update_token() , but in the code SELECT * FROM  horeca_user.update_token(). You just need to use the same syntax I guess

Comment: @a_vlad I just checked that query with PDO connection in pure PHP. Query worked as expected. From here I come to decision that problem associated with Laravel. Below is full code.
$db = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=Horecami;host=127.0.0.1", "postgres", "1" );
$sql = 'Select horeca_user.update_token(?, ?, ?)';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$type=1;
$id=1;
$z='az';
$stmt->bindValue(1, $type, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(3, $z, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$res=$stmt->fetchAll();

Comment: ok, is string copy/pasted? what about unnesessary \ in  $token=\DB::select ?

Comment: no "\" this means root namespace. It does not matter.